# Hyper parameter tuning on pipeline object

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I have this pipeline,

```
pl = Pipeline([
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list = [
            ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                ("selector", get_numeric_data),
        ])),
            ('text_features', Pipeline([
                ("selector",get_text_data),
                ("vectorizer", HashingVectorizer(token_pattern=TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC,non_negative=True, norm=None, binary=False, ngram_range=(1,2))),
                ('dim_red', SelectKBest(chi2, chi_k))
            ]))
         ])), ("clf",LogisticRegression())
    ])
```

When I try to do

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
c_space = np.logspace(-5, 8, 15)
param_grid = {"C": c_space,"penalty": ['l1', 'l2']}
logreg_cv = GridSearchCV(pl,param_grid=param_grid,cv=5)
logreg_cv.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

It throws me

> ValueError: Invalid parameter penalty for estimator
>   Pipeline(memory=None,
>        steps=[('union', FeatureUnion(n_jobs=1,
>        transformer_list=[('numeric_features', Pipeline(memory=None,
>        steps=[('selector', FunctionTransformer(accept_sparse=False,
>        func= at 0x00000190ECB49488>, inv_kw_args=None,
>        inverse_func=None, kw_args=None, pass_y=...ty='l2', random_state=None, 
>        solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
>        verbose=0, warm_start=False))]). Check the list of available parameters 
>        with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

Although "C" and "penalty" legit parameters in this case. Please help me hoe to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"C" and "penalty" are legit parameters of LogisticRegression, not Pipeline object that you send to GridSearchCV.

Your pipeline currently have two components, `"union"` and `"clf"`. Now the pipeline dont know which part to send the paramters. You need to append these names used in pipeline with params, so that it can identify them and send them to correct object.

Do this:

```
param_grid = {"clf__C": c_space,"clf__penalty": ['l1', 'l2']}
```

Note that there are two underscores in between the name of object in pipeline and the parameters.

Its mentioned in the documentation of [Pipeline and FeatureUnion here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html):

> Parameters of the estimators in the pipeline can be accessed using the
>   __ syntax

With various examples to demonstrate the usage.

Following this, if you want to say change the `ngram_range` of HashingVectorizer, you would do this:

```
"union__text_features__vectorizer__ngram_range" : [(1,3)]
```